# Execute PowerShell script on my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shell, powershell, active-directory

I looked everywhere on how to set a script on my rails app but nothing accurate.
Actually I want to create new users on Active Directory through a form which is on my app.

The idea is to let the user create his profile on the app (name,email, password), then the script will do the work to add the credentials on Active Directory.

Do you have any idea to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Check this link, might help you get there:

http://codingbee.net/tutorials/ruby/ruby-use-backticks-and-system-to-run-bash-or-powershell-commands/

I've tested it out a bit, and you can use a script that's expecting parameters. Something like:

```
system('powershell -File C:\Temp\CreateADUser.ps1 -Name "Name" -Email "Email" -Password "Password"')
```

All the heavy lifting would be done by the script, assuming it's going to be run in the context of an account with the right delegations.